# Why is my Giant despawning, and how do I prevent it?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

In one of my worlds, I am trying to summon a Giant that will not despawn. I can successfully summon the Giant, and then I name it with a Name Tag so it doesn't despawn. I also do the same thing with several other nearby caged mobs. Then I leave the area, and when I come back all of the mobs are still there except for the Giant. I know Giants are unused mobs, this may be why it despawns. If that's the reason why it is despawning, how can I prevent it?

Comment: [I found a site that could help you...](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-discussion/redstone-discussion-and/command-blocks/381861-learn-the-summon-command-mobs) `/summon Skeleton 0 ~ 0 {Equipment:[{id:261},{},{},{},{id:306}],PersistenceRequired:1}`

Answer (score 2):

I do not know why the giant is despawning but the only thing I have to suggest is when you summon him in add the `{PersistenceRequired:1}` tag. This should prevent minecraft from despawning it normally.

Here is the full command incase you wanted it.

```
/summon Giant ~ ~1 ~ {PersistenceRequired:1}
```